# SSRS How to replicate Column Total in each row

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

```
Team    Sales   TotalSales
A       10      70
B       25      70
C       30      70
D       5       70
```

I have a dataset for an example please refer the above. The total sales for all 4 teams are 70. I wanted to replicate Grandtotal e.g.70 for each Row on a Matrix. Is it possible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a column with the expression

```
=SUM(Fields.Sales.Value, "mydataSetname")
```

Remember to click the check mark if you think an answer has solved you question instead of just voting up. Remember and answer is good if if answers you actual question, if you have left information out of your question and you still have an issue, start a new question.

Comment: Thanks. The syntax worked. Please ignore my previous comment. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem and thanks for marking as answered. This helps others find solutions without having to search unanswered questions too, so everyone wins ! :)